# How to replicate this P-value given $r$ and $n$?

Tags: p-value

I am using http://www.socscistatistics.com/pvalues/pearsondistribution.aspx as my reference here.

$r = 0.0789$

$n = 15$

The $P$-value is $0.779858$. I have tried to replicate it without success. Is this something where I need $t = r\frac{\sqrt{n-2}}{\sqrt{1-r^2}} = 0.285367618996$ somehow? How do I compute $P$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the formula you provided, we know that

$$
r\frac{\sqrt{n-2}}{\sqrt{1-r^2}} 
$$

is T distributed with $n-2$ degrees of freedom. So then if we use `R` we have:

```
> pt(0.285367618996, 13, lower.tail=F) # one tailed  
[1] 0.3899292  
> 2*pt(0.285367618996, 13, lower.tail=F) # two tailed  
[1] 0.7798585
```

which is the answer provided on the website.

Comment: Is there a way to compute the value without R?

Comment: You can use the CDF that is described on [wikipedia for the t-distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) to calculate the appropriate p-values. Though I would highly recommend using a programming language or a table.

Comment: I am very comfortable with programming but don't know what to analyze. You're saying I need to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function somehow?

Comment: There isn't a closed form for the solution of a t-distribution, so there isn't really an easy formula which you can just program away, so I would recommend you use something that is already written and tested or use a table of values. Otherwise implementing this programmatically without libraries is beyond my knowledge and expertise.

Comment: [Simpson's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#Composite_Simpson.27s_rule) is a quick-and-dirty numerical integration method that is dead easy to implement (it might still be taught in elementary Calculus courses) and will produce reasonable values of the cumulative Student t distribution.  In this example it could even be even done with pencil and paper to an accuracy of better than one part per million using only *two* evaluations of the integrand (at $0.2853676$ and  $0.2853676/2$).